# convert index based for loop in java 8

Tags: java-8

is it possible to convert below given for loop into java 8 code?

```
 Object[] args = pjp.getArgs();
    MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getStaticPart()
            .getSignature();
    Method method = methodSignature.getMethod();
    Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    StringBuilder methodArgs = new StringBuilder();
    for (int argIndex = 0; argIndex < args.length; argIndex++) {
        for (Annotation annotation : parameterAnnotations[argIndex]) {
            if ((annotation instanceof RequestParam) || (annotation instanceof PathVariable) || (annotation instanceof RequestHeader)) {
                methodArgs.append(args[argIndex] + "|");
            } else if ((annotation instanceof RequestBody)) {
                methodArgs.append(mapper.writeValueAsString(args[argIndex]) + "|");
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried with below given java 8 code. function name is randomly taken

```
public void some() {
    Annotation[][] parameterAnnotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();
    Arrays.stream(parameterAnnotations)
            .map(f -> asd(f));
}

private Object asd(Annotation[] annotations) {
    Arrays.stream(annotations)
            .map(a -> change(a)); //here is problem...how i can access args[argIndex]
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Ravindra Ranwala Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to open an `InsStream` to iterate over the `args` index, then create a `SimpleEntry` of each `arg` with it's corresponding `annotaton`(acc. to your code), then you can apply your business logic.

```
IntStream.range(0, args.length)
        .mapToObj(argIndex -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(args[argIndex], parameterAnnotations[argIndex]))
        .flatMap(objectSimpleEntry -> Arrays.stream(objectSimpleEntry.getValue()).map(annotation -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(objectSimpleEntry.getKey(), annotation)))
        .forEach(objectAnnotationSimpleEntry -> {
          Annotation annotation = objectAnnotationSimpleEntry.getValue();
          Object arg = objectAnnotationSimpleEntry.getKey();
          if ((annotation instanceof RequestParam) || (annotation instanceof PathVariable) || (annotation instanceof RequestHeader)) {
            methodArgs.append(arg + "|");
          } else if ((annotation instanceof RequestBody)) {
            methodArgs.append(arg + "|");
          }
        });
```